# How to refresh div and change that div css class after refresh?

Tags: ajax, jsf

Below is my code:

```
      <c:forEach items="#{myBean.contractList}" var="contract">
         <tr>
            <td>#{contract.title}</td>
            <td>#{contract.terms}</td>
            <td> 
                 <h:form>
                 <h:commandLink> 
                   <p:ajax event="click" update=":panelID" listener="#{bean.selectProject(contractID)}"/>
                 </h:commandLink> 
                 </h:form>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </c:forEach>

      <h:panelGroup id="panelID">
        <div id="contractDIV" class="closePopup">
           Full Details of particular contract 
        </div>
      </h:panelGroup>
```

There is contract list with title,terms,name and also "link/button". When I click that link/button, that particular contract details open in another div with ID "contractDIV" from database and  css class name change to "closePopup" from "openPopup". How its possible in JSF ?

Comment: Please show us _What have you tried so far ?_ . _How its possible in JSF_ is not valid question here

Comment: What are you using Primeaces or Richfaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that link/button would have to be a JSF component. Second, that div should also be a JSF component. From there, it's pretty straight forward.

**UPDATE**

Change `event="click"` to `event="action"`, and use something like this to controll which class is applied to the div `class="#{bean.someBoolean ? 'closePopup' : 'openPopup'}"`. You can change `#{bean.someBoolean}` value in `#{bean.selectProject()}` method

Comment: I am using <div id="contractDIV"> inside <h:panelGroup id="panelID"> and also using <h:commandLink> <p:ajax event="click" update=":panelID" listener="#{bean.selectProject(p)}"/></h:commandLink>

Answer (score 0):

Rather then a div have outputpanel
Consider Id which is generated for the outputpanel is **form:refreshPanel**

```
<h:form id="form">
   <c:forEach items="#{myBean.contractList}" var="contract">
     <tr>
        <td>#{contract.title}</td>
        <td>#{contract.terms}</td>
        <td><p:commandLink actionListener="#{bean.method(contract)}"  update=":form:refreshPanel" /></td>
     </tr>
  </c:forEach>
<p:outputPanel styleClass="closePopup" id="form:refreshPanel"> </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

So the content will be refreshed once the processing of actionListener is finished

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to change the class in `oncomplete` of `p:ajax`.

Something like:

```
<p:ajax event="click" update=":panelID" listener="#{bean.selectProject(contractID)}" oncomplete="openPopup();"/>

function openPopup(){
    //your js code
}
```